# What is the meaning of "S" and "L : V" in the context of set/graph theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, notation

In [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3214706/671348) I had asked about notation in graph theory to identify different classes of vertices in a graph.

[One of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3214729/671348) gives the following example, which I'm trying to understand more fully.

> Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a set of (disjoint) sets we will use for vertices
>   of a graph $G = (V, E)$. Define $L: V \to \mathcal{V}$ by setting
>   $L(v) = S$ when $v \in S \in \mathcal{V}$.

I'm not familiar with logic / set theory / graph theory notation, but can parse (and translate into natural language) some of it, but not all of it. I'm having trouble translating

> Define $L : V \to \mathcal{V}$ by setting $L(v) = S$

Is the following "translation" correct?

$L$ is a list function of $V$ to $\mathcal{V}$, which "classifies" a vertex $v$ (the $L(v)$ part) as an element of the set $S$ (which is a set of vertices of the same type ("class")).

Or is $L$ a list of (classes of) elements of $V$, and $S$ is a specific class set (i.e., a set in $\mathcal{V}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to avoid the word "list" when it comes to functions because that term can have mental baggage.

All that line is saying is that $L$ is a function which takes as input any vertex and outputs the class to which that vertex belongs.

It's analogous to defining $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \{\text{odd}, \text{even}\}$ as the function that takes any integer and outputs whether it's even or odd.